# Testing R6 classes

Tags: r, unit-testing, r6

Are there any frameworks out there for testing object-oriented R code, say R6 classes, that is comparable to JUnit?

As a software engineer coming from the Java world, I find testing R code surprisingly cumbersome when compared to using JUnit for Java or scalatest for Scala.

Comment: Have you checked [`testthat`](https://testthat.r-lib.org/). R6 itself has unit tests using the `testthat` package (see [here](https://github.com/r-lib/R6/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-nonportable.R)).

Comment: What @David said -- `testthat` is an easy and convenient but flexible package for testing R code, including code with `R6` classes